# Pyspark create a summary table with calculated values

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----+
|tpep_pickup_datetime|tpep_dropoff_datetime|trip_distance|total_amount|isDay|
+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----+
| 2019-01-01 09:01:00|  2019-01-01 08:53:20|          1.5|        2.00| true|
| 2019-01-01 21:59:59|  2019-01-01 21:18:59|          2.6|        5.00|false|
| 2019-01-01 10:01:00|  2019-01-01 08:53:20|          1.5|        2.00| true|
| 2019-01-01 22:59:59|  2019-01-01 21:18:59|          2.6|        5.00|false|
+--------------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----+
```

and I want to create a summary table which calculates the `trip_rate` for all the night trips and all the day trips (`total_amount` column divided by `trip_distance`). So the end result should look like this:

```
+------------+-----------+
| day_night  | trip_rate |
+------------+-----------+
|Day         | 1.33      |
|Night       | 1.92      |
+------------+-----------+
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('2019-01-01 09:01:00','2019-01-01 08:53:20','1.5','2.00','true'),#day
        ('2019-01-01 21:59:59','2019-01-01 21:18:59','2.6','5.00','false'),#night
        ('2019-01-01 10:01:00','2019-01-01 08:53:20','1.5','2.00','true'),#day
        ('2019-01-01 22:59:59','2019-01-01 21:18:59','2.6','5.00','false'),#night
    ],
    ['tpep_pickup_datetime','tpep_dropoff_datetime','trip_distance','total_amount','day_night'] # add your columns label here
)

day_trip_rate = df2.where(df2.day_night == 'Day').withColumn("trip_rate",F.sum("total_amount")/F.sum("trip_distance"))
night_trip_rate = df2.where(df2.day_night == 'Night').withColumn("trip_rate",F.sum("total_amount")/F.sum("trip_distance"))
```

I don't believe I'm even approaching it the right way. And I'm getting this error:(
`raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace) pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "grouping expressions sequence is empty, and '`tpep_pickup_datetime`' is not an aggregate function.`

Can someone help me know how to approach this to get that summary table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df2.groupBy("day_night").agg(F.round(F.sum("total_amount")/F.sum("trip_distance"),2).alias('trip_rate'))\
        .withColumn("day_night", F.when(col("day_night")=="true", "Day").otherwise("Night")).show()

+---------+---------+
|day_night|trip_rate|
+---------+---------+
|      Day|     1.33|
|    Night|     1.92|
+---------+---------+
```

Without rounding off:

```
df2.groupBy("day_night").agg(F.sum("total_amount")/F.sum("trip_distance")).alias('trip_rate')\
        .withColumn("day_night", F.when(col("day_night")=="true", "Day").otherwise("Night")).show()
```

(You have `day_night` in `df2` construction code, but `isDay` in the display table. I'm considering the field name as `day_night` here.)

Comment: Thanks again Cena. You are my hero, you even catch my posting mistakes. That worked perfectly.